# rails can‘t use code to generate form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

my view code(`index.slim`) is this:

```
-form_tag do
   Form contents
```

but this doesn't generate a form,nothing I will get,why?

my rails version is `3.2.14` .and I just generate this project through `rails new blog` to study rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to use the outputting version of the `form_tag` helper?

```
= form_tag do
```

Comment: That's nice, don't forget to pick my answer as the correct one. :)